# Setting ArcMap layout size based on web unit (pixel) standard?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, resolution

I need to export my map from ArcMap as SVG and display it on a web page in an exact size of 500x500 pixels, like this:

```
<div id="mapSVG" style=" width: 500px;  height: 500px;"></div>
```

Can you please let me know how I can set up the size of the layout to be exactly 500px in height and width?

I already found out how to change the size of the layout from File -> Page And Print Set up but in Map Page size there only 4 options available: Points, Inches, Centimeters and Millimeters.

Is Points equal to px in web? If not how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Print dialog in ArcGIS isn't set up to directly input pixel units. You have to do a little math and set two different parameters to get the output you want.

First, in the page setup, **uncheck** the box that says use printer paper settings and enter a value of 5 inches for width and height.

[image]

Next, when you go to export your svg, you need to do a little math and set the appropriate dpi setting. You might want to do the math beforehand to know how many inches to use. In your case you want a square 500 pixel image. So the easy math is to make the image 5 inches on a side and use a dpi (dots per inch) value of 100. 100 pixels per inch over 5 inches is 500 pixels.

[image]

It's odd that, as you can see in the first image, they offer a Screen page size, but even if you select that it doesn't enable using pixels for units. There's also a Slide page size, which defaults to 10 x 7.5 inches. The only way to really control output in pixel dimensions is to use the math between page size and resolution, setting both appropriately.

BTW, points is a completely different unit, mostly related to fonts. There are 72 points in an inch. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)